# Domain Driven Design Aggregations

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

This question is really about aggregations, NOT aggregation roots.
Consider you have an entity for cars. the application displays a list (aggregations) of every "car level". for example the first level could be the car manufacturer.

like 
Audi,
VW,
...

This list is an aggregation of my "car"-entity.

is there a good approach how to handle such "aggregated views" of an entity?
is this an value object inside my domain?

Should i end up with 4 classes describing cars? this would be a lot of duplicated code?
Or should i use the fully "Car"-entity for every level as representation but using a Interface to specify the fields you can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Domain Driven Design, an aggregate is accessible only by it's root. an aggregate could be consist of entities and value objects. based on your needs you can have lot's of feature for your domain(they should not be persisted as an entity or value object).
now in your example you can have Car entity (and also it could be the root of your aggregate) and have lot's feature for this entity, for example a car manufacture is obviously a value object.

**Should i end up with 4 classes describing cars? this would be a lot of duplicated code? Or should i use the fully "Car"-entity for every level as representation but using a Interface to specify the fields you can access?**

as I mentioned you can have lot's of enums, classes , interfaces to reduce the duplication of your code but remember that you should finally persist entity and value object.
I advice you to separate the Car features such as Color, Manufacture, Model, ... and collaborate those features in your aggregate root to persist.
it's better you to see some example about DDD in real world applications, take all of [these](http://github.com/elbandit) samples and take a look at [these](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Tag/DDDesign) articles.

Comment: consider my car entity has around 200 different fields (it's the level of detail the entity may has)and the only thing a car entity (fully specified car) to a less specified car called "car level4" is a missing motor code. so my "car level4" isnt a real entity but shares 199 fields with my car entity. now i want query a list of these "car level4"'s. but what entity i am using to represent this list?

Comment: don't think about database fields when you are modeling your domain, fields of database is a repository concern. just try to model correctly. now if your car has different scenarios you can see the car a module and put different aggregates(you call them level). I have to say again that all depends on your model.

Comment: with fields i mean properties, all in memory. the question is really about modeling. i am not sure what a "car_level4" is, it's not a fully car, so it's not an entiy. should i represent it as an interface and use the car entity? should i use inheritance for the car levels like car_level1 -> car_level2 -> car_level3 -> car_level4 -> car? or better composition? should i create new objects? just want to know if there are any good ways to deal with such "parts" of entities i need to query from a repository?/service?.

Comment: so, if you have multiple kinds of levels for cars in your domain you can have a base "Car level" class and it's properties an inherit other car levels from the base. based on your needs you can query in repository if you want to retrieve the entities and value objects.